# Windows Server 2008 Scheduled Task

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

I'm running windows server 2008, and there's a lot of computers in the workplace. I'd like to be able to run shutdown.exe automatically at about 9PM on *most* of them, with the exception of a few of the administration rooms and the servers themselves. Anyone know how I could do this without having to physically set a scheduled task on each computer by hand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remotely shut down multiple Windows XP PCs (in active directory domain)](http://serverfault.com/questions/83188/remotely-shut-down-multiple-windows-xp-pcs-in-active-directory-domain)

Answer (score 4):

You could script this on a server or admin workstation using psshutdown and feed it a list of the desired workstations.

Comment: Standard shutdown.exe can process remote PCs too (with -m \\COMPUTERNAME option).